# Adding applications petalinux

Tags: linux, fpga, zynq

I have a microzed board based on the xilinx 7000 series with petalinux OS installed and configured on it. There are compilers and support for C/C++ applications. However, how do I add and get applications like PERL/python compilers and scripts working on this OS ?

Comment: If you absolutely need `petalinux` and want to extend it you must read the documentation. Each GNU/Linux environment has its own way to do this (the `apt` package management system on `debian`, for instance). If `petalinux` has no package management system, which is possible as it targets tiny embedded systems, you will probably have to compile what is missing form the sources. Apparently `petalinux` comes with the development tools, so it should be possible. In case you do not absolutely need `petalinux` I suggest having a look at `buildroot`. It has what you need.

Answer (score 4):

You can enable quite a few packages using:

petalinux-config -c rootfs

Or you can manually create Petalinux "component" by using appropriate command(you will have to create/copy sources and/or binaries into component directory and create petalinux component Makefile):

```
petalinux-create -t apps -n settings --enable

petalinux-create -t libs -n settings --enable
```

But be aware that Petalinux targeting embedded environments with total image sizes below 40Mb. So at some point it makes more sense to switch to something like "linaro" distribution, which will allow you to use Ubuntu apt-get.

Answer (score 3):

I put up the process of cross compiling Python 2.7.3 into a PetaLinux app.

Please check:

http://www.github.com/imrickysu/PetaLinux-Apps/blob/master/components/apps/python-2.7.3/README.md